# PDB and line length formatting

Tags: python, code-formatting, pdb

Some collaborators on a project are encouraging the use of the automatic code formatting tool `black`. Unfortunately, some of its decisions clash with my aesthetic intuitions, but more importantly, the way it breaks code on multiple lines interferes with the way I use the Python debugger, `pdb`. I was wondering if anyone else has this problem or knows of a way around it.

Here is a mini example of the kind of thing I encounter:

```
def add5_with_long_kwargs(long_kwarg1=1, long_kwarg2=2, long_kwarg3=3, long_kwarg4=4, long_kwarg5=5):
    return long_kwarg1 + long_kwarg2 + long_kwarg3 + long_kwarg4 + long_kwarg5

def add_12345():
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    breakpoint()
    x = add5_with_long_kwargs(long_kwarg1=x1, long_kwarg2=x2, long_kwarg3=x3, long_kwarg4=x4, long_kwarg5=x5)
    return x

add_12345()
```

My typical debugging workflow:

1. I put a `breakpoint` on the line above the function call, and the code stops there to let me inspect the current values of the variables.
2. Then I can step to the next line using the `next` (or `n`) command of `pdb`, which will let me inspect/manipulate the calculated variable `x`.

Obviously this example is trivial, but it's representative of many real-world situations, particularly when calling a function with lots of keyword arguments.

Now, when I run `black` on the code using line length 80, it alters it to look like:

```
def add5_with_long_kwargs(
    long_kwarg1=1, long_kwarg2=2, long_kwarg3=3, long_kwarg4=4, long_kwarg5=5
):
    return long_kwarg1 + long_kwarg2 + long_kwarg3 + long_kwarg4 + long_kwarg5


def add_12345():
    x1, x2, x3, x4, x5 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    breakpoint()
    x = add5_with_long_kwargs(
        long_kwarg1=x1,
        long_kwarg2=x2,
        long_kwarg3=x3,
        long_kwarg4=x4,
        long_kwarg5=x5,
    )
    return x


add_12345()
```

Now when I run the code, I have to step *7 times*(!) to get from the breakpoint to the next "logical line" in order to inspect `x`. This is very annoying and time-consuming.

Similar troubles arise in the case of a long list comprehension broken over several lines, etc.

Possible workarounds are to set multiple breakpoints, or (if not done in advance) set one to a specific line interactively. But both of these options incur extra overhead. Ideally `pdb` would have an option like "step *n* lines ahead," but to my knowledge it can't do that.

In any case, I find this situation rather frustrating, one reason (among many) that I am not fond of code auto-formatters. I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!